# How set title of a WKInterfaceButton?

Tags: objective-c, watchkit

I'm trying to change the text of a button once it is pressed however it doesn't work. Am i missing something?

i've been trying to figure my problem for hours.
any help would be appreciated.

h. file

```
#import <WatchKit/WatchKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface InterfaceController : WKInterfaceController
{

    IBOutlet WKInterfaceButton*playpausebtn;
}
-(IBAction)play;
@end
```

m. file

```
#import "InterfaceController.h"
#import <WatchConnectivity/WatchConnectivity.h>


@interface InterfaceController() <WCSessionDelegate>

@end


@implementation InterfaceController

- (void)awakeWithContext:(id)context {
    [super awakeWithContext:context];

    // Configure interface objects here.
}
- (void)willActivate {
    [super willActivate];

    if ([WCSession isSupported]) {
        WCSession *session = [WCSession defaultSession];
        session.delegate = self;
        [session activateSession];



    }

}

- (void)didDeactivate {
    // This method is called when watch view controller is no longer visible
    [super didDeactivate];
}




-(IBAction)play{
    [playpausebtn setTitle:@"sleep"];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**It is working fine in Swift-3 Xcode-8.1 .**

//  InterfaceController.swift
//  WatchKit Extension
import WatchKit
import Foundation
import WatchConnectivity

class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController,WCSessionDelegate {

```
@IBOutlet var textLabel: WKInterfaceLabel!

var session:WCSession?

override func awake(withContext context: Any?) {
    super.awake(withContext: context)

    // Configure interface objects here.
}

override func willActivate() {
    // This method is called when watch view controller is about to be visible to user
    super.willActivate()
    checkSupportOfSession()
    changeAttributeOfText()
}

@IBOutlet var buttonOutlet: WKInterfaceButton!

override func didDeactivate() {
    // This method is called when watch view controller is no longer visible
    super.didDeactivate()
}

func checkSupportOfSession() {
    if( WCSession.isSupported() ) {
        self.session = WCSession.default()
        self.session?.delegate = self
        self.session?.activate()
    }
}

func session(_ session: WCSession, activationDidCompleteWith activationState: WCSessionActivationState, error: Error?) {
    print("session")
}

func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : Any]) {

    let message:String = message["textIndex"] as! String
    textLabel.setText(message)
    print(message)

}

func changeAttributeOfText() {

    let paragraphStyle =  NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraphStyle.alignment = .left
    let font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 12)
    let attributes:Dictionary = [NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:paragraphStyle ,  NSFontAttributeName:font ]

    let attributeString:NSAttributedString = NSAttributedString(string: "HELLO", attributes: attributes)
    textLabel.setAttributedText(attributeString)

}

 //Change the ButtonTitle after click
 @IBAction func buttonClicked() {
     buttonOutlet.setTitle("textNew")
 }}
```

[Demo App](https://github.com/shrawan2015/Application-Demo-StackOverFlow/tree/master/WatchOS)

Comment: Why put so much unnecessary code? If you delete everything, that's unrelated to the question, it would be easier to understand.